# revised manuscript

Tags: publications, editors

I have got major revision from biosensor and bioelectronics and the deadline was 1 month. I finished revision within 10 days and submitted the revised paper. now for one week it is with editor. when can I get a decision from the editor? two reviewers gave minor revision, but still, an editor named it major revision.
Thanks

Comment: The only person who can answer this is the editor.

Answer (score 2):

One week is not very long, especially when the editor gave you a month and likely expected to look at your manuscript after that month's time. If you haven't heard from them in a few more weeks, get in contact with them again. Until then, be patient and remember yours isn't the only paper they are working on.

Comment: One week is a mere instant in "editor time".